# Deploying ASP.NET Core RC2 Application to Azure

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, asp.net-core

For a few months I've successfully deployed my ASP.NET Core application to Azure with continuous integration.

More recently I am no longer able to do it because I got a set of different errors.

**Targeting coreclr:**

- the cgi application did not return a valid set of http errors
- the specified cgi application encountered an error and the server terminated the process rc1

I've tried also **targeting only the full .NET** but I got the following error:

- you do not have permission to view this directory or page

I have also seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Deploy-an-AspNet-vNext-application-to-Microsoft-Azure-websites) that they are currently using the dotnet cli, but I don't think this could lead to the errors that I got.

Do you have any ideas about how to deploy a ASP.NET Core application (built with yeoman, VisualStudioCode, hippie things, etc.) on Azure with continuous integration?

Comment: There is no vNext rc2...

Comment: I had this exact same issue when porting my rc1 app.  I couldn't figure it out which setting was causing it.  So I created a new RC2 app, copied across all the code I needed to get it working again and redeployed and now it works... /shrug

Answer (score 4):

I had the same and discovered that **web.config** wasn't being updated correctly when running `dotnet publish`.
Specifically the parameters were not getting replaced, and the command was throwing errors about **web.config** not existing.

The published **web.config** was being generated with the following

`<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>`

but needed to be

`<aspNetCore processPath=".\Focus.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />`

with **Focus.exe** being generated from the name of my project.

I narrowed the cause down to running `dotnet publish` from a directory other than the project directory itself.

I've filed a bug at https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3576 and documented it all at https://www.dwen.co.nz/2016/06/15/asp-dotnet-core-rc2-and-azure/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/azure-app-service-and-asp-net-core-rc2/) that was posted yesterday. It describes how to successfully deploy an ASP.NET Core RC2 app onto Azure App Services.

Comment: That refers to a script that isn't there. That post isn't useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the runtime. If you are using RC1, make sure that the connection strings, application settings (In Azure if you are using any) and services are targeting the correct database. I'd the same issue then I came to know that my application settings and connecting string are not found in production. I rectify and everything is up and running.